# why Control M OS Job that executes an exe gets stuck mid execution?

Tags: c#, windows, control-m

I have a c# exe that reads some log lines from a remote unix server using sed. when I run this exe several times on my windows server or even my dev pc, it executes fine. However, when I try to run it as a cyclic OS job in Control M eventually (sometimes at the first execution, seems to happen at random) it gets stuck but doesn't throw an exception or anything.

The command of the job runs a .bat file, and the cyclic is configured to 0 minutes with pause time being controlled dynamically by the exe with a thread.sleep.

after searching the web and seeking recommendation from other areas of my workplace that use control M, I have so far tried changing my agent to use local user with ctmwincfg, I also tried with changing the agent service to the same user (had to reverse this one as the agent stopped working properly), I also changed from directly executing my exe on the job to using a .bat file.

one of my hostgroup agents is windows server 2016 and 3 more are windows server 2012

Comment: Has anyone ever encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able of finding a solution within control M itself, but rather in the code of the .exe. I used a task, it allows the program to terminate the stuck method after a timeout, which in turn allows the control M job to finish normally.

```
  var task = Task.Run(() => MyStuckMethod(arg));
        if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
            return task.Result;
        else
            throw new Exception("Timed out");
```

Alternatively, there are a few workarounds within control M which involve sending alerts or creating shouts and then automating the kill of the job, but this is not useful for my case.
[Example in BMC communities](https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-49292)